# Font not in bold

Tags: r, shiny

In my code below (which works just fine) I would like all the fonts when I hover over country on world map to be either bold or non bold. What is happening is as per the following example - say I hover over USA then I get  .
562,079 Deaths United States **USA**
**Cases: 30,211,178
Population: 320,635,163
Deaths % by Population:v0.0097%**

The "Deaths United Sates" is not bold.
Code

```
   output$World_Map <- renderPlotly({
        l <- list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)
        g <- list(
            showframe = FALSE,
            showcoastlines = FALSE,
            projection = list(type = "kavrayskiy7")
        )
        
        fig <- plot_geo(worldmap)
        fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
            z = ~ worldmap$Deaths,
            color = ~ worldmap$Deaths,
            colors = 'Reds',
            locations = ~ worldmap$Country_Alpha_Code,
            marker = list(line = l),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~ glue::glue(
                "Deaths: {Country.x} <b>{Country_Alpha_Code}<b>\nCases: {comma(Cases,digits=0)}<b>\nPopulation: {comma(Population,digits=0)}<b>\nDeaths % by Population: {comma(Deaths_Perc_Pop,digits=4)}%</b>"
            ),
            hovertemplate = "%{z:,0f}<extra>%{text}</extra>"
        )
        fig <-
            fig %>% colorbar(title = 'Deaths - Positive Cases Gradient', tickformat = ",0f")
        fig <-
            fig %>% layout(title = 'Covid19 Global Pandemic .... <br>Data Source:<a href="https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/">Johns Hopkins University of Medicine</a>',
                           geo = g)
        fig
    })
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe try to put  `<b>` just before `{Country.x}` and not after? Or just before `Deaths: `. Not sure it's what you're searching for

Comment: Thanks - that did it.

Comment: Thanks for this tip